# modal dialog over Activex control

Tags: jquery, css, activex, modal-dialog

I use jQuery modal dialogs (jQuery UI) for modal popups.It is working fine, until recently we installed an activex plugin. Now, when ever the plug in is activated, this popup goes behind the plugin.Is there any way to show the modal dialog on top of activex plugin ?

Browsers: IE7,IE8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an activex plugin on hand to test with, but I believe if you can hide the plugin behind an iframe.  When you display your modal popup, create an empty iframe.  Give it the same dimensions as your popup, and display it at the same location, but with a lower `z-index`.  The iframe should render above the activex plugin, and your popup should render above the iframe.

I can verify that this technique works for masking `<select />` boxes in IE6.  I haven't tested it myself with ActiveX controls, but Google [tells me](http://www.macridesweb.com/oltest/IframeShim.html) it should work.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Douglas' answer. jQuery UI's dialog includes a [`bgiframe` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#options) that is meant to fix these types of z-index issues using the iframe solution. Simply setting the option to true *should* fix your problem.